# Synchronizing rest service using JAVA Spring

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, rest, synchronization

I have a POST request that I would like to synchronize based on the incoming request body POJO. The request body has a variable by which I can identify if the incoming request is a duplicate or not.

My problem is that each incoming request body has a different reference.
I am generating some sort of confirmation number with the sample request body. I am getting multiple confirmation numbers for the same identifier(property inside SampleRequestBody class) which I don't want.

```
@PostMapping(value = "testingSync", headers = {"Content-type=application/json"})
public void testingSync(@RequestBody SampleRequestBody sampleRequestBody) {
    synchronized(sampleRequestBody) {
        //Do some process with the sample request body
    }       
}
```

The sample request body looks something like this

```
public class SampleRequestBody {

private String identifier;

public String getIdentifier(){
return this.identifier;
}
public void setIdentifier(String identifier){
this.identifier = identifier;
}
}
```

Comment: I don't fully understand your problem. You sampleRequestBody in this scenario, is never acessed by two theards since it's local to the testingSync method.

Comment: @ricardofagodoy When multiple requests come with the same request body I need to process them one after another.

Comment: And what exactly is not working?

Comment: Assume I am generating some sort of confirmation number with the sample request body. I am getting multiple confirmation numbers for the same identifier(property inside SampleRequestBody class) which I don't want.

Comment: If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Answer (score 2):

The `synchronized` block synchronizes calls that are using the **same instance**. As each call to your service will create a new instance of `SampleRequestBody` there is practically no synchronization.

You could synchronize on the `identifier` property of you request object by storing the strings in some kind of local cache in order to get the same string instance for the same identifier again:

```
// you should not actually use String.intern() here but some local cache
synchronized(sampleRequestBody.getIdentifier().intern()) {
    //Do some process with the sample request body
}
```

The above example uses `String.intern()` just for the sake of simplicity. In a real live application using `String.intern()` should be avoided as it will create objects in memory that are not covered by the Java GC. That is: use a local cache instead.

You should additionally keep in mind that this synchronization will only work on a per JVM basis. That is, if you got two servers in a load balanced setup, this will not work as desired.

And one last thought: You should really rethink the need of synchronization here. Use it only if there is no other possibility to solve your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Mine is a load balanced setup so I am not sure about the intern() method. Is there any workaround for this? Or do you propose any other solution?

Comment: If you really need cross JVM sychronization you will either have to use some tools like hazelcast or implement something on your own, or give this project a try https://github.com/alturkovic/distributed-lock (first hit on google for: jdbc based distributed lock)

Answer (score 2):

If you need a tool to synchronization by the value of the object which you can use in Spring Framework then I can suggest you [XSync](https://github.com/antkorwin/xsync) library.

All that you need is to add the `XSync` bean in your configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class Config{
    @Bean
    public XSync<String> xSync(){
        return new XSync<>();
    }
}
```

and now you can use it in your controller:

```
@Autowired
private XSync<String> xSync;

@PostMapping(value = "testingSync", headers = {"Content-type=application/json"})
public void testingSync(@RequestBody SampleRequestBody sampleRequestBody) {

    xSync.execute(sampleRequestBody.getIdentifier(), () -> {  
        //Do some process with the sample request 
    });       
}
```

Implementation of this library based on the `WeakReference` instead of `String.intern`.

Using `String.intern` here is a bad idea, you can get a deadlock and memory leaks.